# Looking for something to write troubleshooting scripts

Tags: documentation

At the moment all our troubleshooting doc is written in Word.  I'd like to make it a little user friendlier - first idea was just to write it in HTML with something like :

```
<p>Is the server up? <a href="#Step21">Yes>/a>
```

To at least make the navigation easier.  But surely someone is way ahead of me. Is there any best practice in this area?  Any good tools?  Any suggestions?  My team's primarily java based but can work with a range of operating systems and languages so all suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like an ideal job for a wiki.  There are lots of different platforms you might try; personally I prefer [moinmoin](http://moinmo.in/).

Comment: Damn, we've got a wiki up and running.  Let's see how badly the corporate install team mangled it before I mark this as the answer.  They have a talent for blocking every useful feature.